# How to use chmod to change the permissions of a file, with a variable

Tags: bash, chmod

I'm trying to change the permission of a file, and I have the path of the file stored in an array.

```
chmod 744 ${arrayOfFiles[1]}
```

The 1 is just a placeholder, as in reality it is `i` within a for loop. But whenever I run this command I get this error:

```
chmod: missing operand after ‘744’
```

and I'm not sure why. I have checked that the `${arrayOfFiles[1]}` actually contains the full path and it does.

I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
local i=0
filePermission="-rwxr--r--"
directoryPermission="-rwxr-xr-x"
for (( i=0; i<=${#arrayOfFilePermissions[@]}; i++))
do
    if [ "${arrayOfFilePermissions[$i]}" != "$filePermission" ]; then
        echo "File ${arrayOfFiles[$i]} has the wrong permission: ${arrayOfFilePermissions[$i]}"
        echo ${arrayOfFiles[$i]}
        chmod 744 ${arrayOfFiles[$i]}
        echo "This has been changed to: $filePermission"
    fi
done
```

The array arrayOfFiles contain the file names, and the arrayOfPermissions contain the permissions. I am trying to make all the permission `rwxr--r--`.

The if statement is running, it's just that where ever I am trying to get the value from the array it fails, and draws a blank

Comment: Your `chmod` looks good to me. Can you (1) show how your array is defined, and (2) perform an `echo` of the value at index `1` just before the `chmod` in your script?

Comment: Looks like it's probably a typo somewhere as you'd only get that error if the value of `${arrayOfFiles[1]}` is blank.

Comment: Please note that arrays created like `things=( zero one two three four )`  start at index 0 not 1.

Comment: @chrisaycock `declare -a arrayOfFiles` Is that what you mean? I'm very new to bash so I'm not sure if that's right.

Just tried the `echo` , and it prints a blank so that's where the problem is I guess. When I try to `echo`  that elsewhere it works though. So the `echo` is failing only inside the `if` statement but I don't know why.

Comment: @Rikg09 Please post your entire code, or (preferably) the smallest code sample that reproduces your error.

Comment: @chrisaycock I've edited the original question

Comment: @Rikg09 Thanks for the update. Can you post how these arrays are defined? (Not just declared, but the contents are filled-out.)

Comment: @chrisaycock I don't really want to post too much of my code online, but there isn't a problem with the way the contents are being filled. When I echo the contents outside the `for` loop they print out perfectly fine. This leads me to believe there's nothing wrong with the  arrays, but something else

Comment: @Rikg09 The fact that you can print the arrays outside of a loop but not inside a loop tells me that the array definitions are wrong.

Comment: @chrisaycock  `arrayOfFiles=(${arrayOfFiles[@]} $(pwd)/$(ls -Ap | grep -v "/$" | sed -n "${i}p"))` This is how I'm filling the array out

Comment: @Rikg09 Post fake code that reporduces the problem. We don't need your actual code just something that gives the same behaviour.

Comment: @123 I just posted the real code instead, I think that would help a lot more

Comment: @Rikg09 So you are filling the array with itself and then the output of  a command ?

Comment: @123 Essentially yes, I couldn't find an easy way to just add to the array and that's what I came up with when I looked up a way.

Comment: @Rikg09 `Array+=('new element')` does that.

Comment: @123 So it does...I've just changed my code. Thanks for that, it looks a lot cleaner now